# Insert code in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to insert code into  string:

```
<%=link_to ('Sign Up')%>

flash[:notice] = "<%=link_to ('Sign Up')%>"
```

How can I do it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert code into string like that in ruby.

```
"#{code}"
```

For example:

```
"#{1+1}"
>> "2"
```

In your example, it would be:

```
flash[:notice] = "#{link_to ('Sign Up')}"
```

But since `link_to` is already returning a string... why don't you just write:

```
flash[:notice] = link_to('Sign Up')
```

If you need more help, read more about string literals [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals)

Comment: But does this still work if the flash notice is in a controller? I'm trying to do the same thing but with mail_to. However I can't seem to use helpers in a controller, except if i do this:   `flash[:notice] = "bla bla #{view.context.mail_to Setting::MY_EMAIL} bla bla"`   but then my browser prints out the html with tags present rather than processing the code. Any idea how to fix this?